# CreateCriteria sorting on aggregate function sum

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, createcriteria

```
SELECT 
  [ProductErpIdentifier], 
  [PriceValue], 
  [ManufacturerProductIdentifier], 
  SUM([QuantityOrdered]) as  [QuantityOrdered]
FROM 
  [eCommerceDev].[dbo].[OrderItem] 
GROUP BY 
  [ProductErpIdentifier],[PriceValue],[ManufacturerProductIdentifier]
ORDER BY  
  [QuantityOrdered] desc
```

How should I write a CreateCriteria to generate SQL like the example above?

Comment: I need to know your property names if you want running code. please post your mapping of the orderitem entity.

Comment: i am using  .Add(Projections.Alias(Projections.Sum("QuantityOrdered"), "QuantityOrdered")

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick. Due to the fact you did not post your mapping of the orderitem ntity I used the fieldnames as property names. You will need to change OrderItemEntity to your own mapped class, and you need to change the names preceded by oi. by the names of the properties in your class (be aware: these strings are case sensitive!)

```
var yourResult = Session.CreateCriteria<OrderItemEntity>("oi")
                   .SetProjection(Projections.ProjectionList()
                      .Add(Projections.Alias(Projections.GroupProperty("oi.ProductErpIdentifier"), "ProductErpIdentifier"))
                      .Add(Projections.Alias(Projections.GroupProperty("oi.PriceValue"), "PriceValue"))
                      .Add(Projections.Alias(Projections.GroupProperty("oi.ManufacturerProductIdentifier"), "ManufacturerProductIdentifier"))
                      .Add(Projections.Alias(Projections.Sum("oi.QuantityOrdered"), "QuantityOrdered")))
                   .AddOrder(Order.Desc("QuantityOrdered"))
                   .List();
```

Comment: thanks for answer  now i get Could not find a setter for property 'SummedQuantityOrdered' in class 'OrderItem' , i need to add som temporary column OrderItem

Comment: iam using this also http://nkpatterson.blogspot.se/2010/12/re-usable-nhibernate-paging-extension.html

Comment: @stefan does it work if you remove the AddOrder? if not, please post the code of your entity (orderitem) and it's mapping file.

Comment: yes it working if remove addorder , it also working if  i sort on other columns

Comment: @stefan I updated the code above, that should work with the addorder as well.